# JavaScript Drop&Down menu selenium Java without value or id

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a problem with click drop-down menu and choosing an option in Selenium. 
I've tried to use `.click()` method but it did not work.

I´m newbie with selenium and looking for a solution but I've not found anything which works appropriate.

I paste the code from the button and from the menu in JavaScript and two screenshot for the process

**BUTTON**

```
<div id="wfm-header-config" class="header-cell jqx-widget jqx-widget-officeWFM2 jqx-menu jqx-menu-officeWFM2 jqx-rtl jqx-rtl-officeWFM2 jqx-widget-header jqx-widget-header-officeWFM2 jqx-menu-horizontal jqx-menu-horizontal-officeWFM2 jqx-rc-all jqx-rc-all-officeWFM2 dis_jqxMenu" role="menubar" style="outline: medium none; height: auto; background-color: transparent; background-image: none; border: medium none;" tabindex="0">
<ul class="jqx-menu-ul">
<li id="-1" class="jqx-rtl jqx-rtl-officeWFM2 jqx-item jqx-item-officeWFM2 jqx-menu-item-top jqx-menu-item-top-officeWFM2 jqx-rc-all jqx-rc-all-officeWFM2" style="float: right; background-color: transparent; background-image: none; padding: 2px;" role="menuitem">
<img src="resources/images/ic_settings_24.png" title="Configuración ">
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**DROP&DOWN MENU**

```
<div class="jqx-menu-popup jqx-menu-popup jqx-menu-popup-officeWFM2" style="border: medium none; background-color: transparent; z-index: 17000; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; position: absolute; top: 39.3333px; left: 1086.5px; display: none; visibility: visible; width: 159px; height: 124px;">
<div style="background-color: transparent; border: none; position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
<ul id="jqxWidget60bb7a98" class="jqx-widget-content jqx-widget-content-officeWFM2 jqx-menu-dropdown jqx-menu-dropdown-officeWFM2 jqx-popup jqx-popup-officeWFM2 jqx-rc-l jqx-rc-l-officeWFM2 jqx-rc-b jqx-rc-b-officeWFM2" role="menu" style="overflow: hidden; position: absolute; left: 0px; display: block; top: -119px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; padding-left: 2px; padding-right: 2px;">
<li id="0" class="jqx-rtl jqx-rtl-officeWFM2 jqx-item jqx-item-officeWFM2 jqx-menu-item jqx-menu-item-officeWFM2 jqx-rc-all jqx-rc-all-officeWFM2" role="menuitem">
<span style="position: relative; left: 3px; top: -2px;">Perfiles</span>
</li>
<li id="1" class="jqx-rtl jqx-rtl-officeWFM2 jqx-item jqx-item-officeWFM2 jqx-menu-item jqx-menu-item-officeWFM2 jqx-rc-all jqx-rc-all-officeWFM2" role="menuitem">
<span style="position: relative; left: 3px; top: -2px;">Usuarios</span>
</li>
<li id="2" class="jqx-rtl jqx-rtl-officeWFM2 jqx-item jqx-item-officeWFM2 jqx-menu-item jqx-menu-item-officeWFM2 jqx-rc-all jqx-rc-all-officeWFM2" role="menuitem">
<span style="position: relative; left: 3px; top: -2px;">Parámetros</span>
</li>
<li id="3" class="jqx-rtl jqx-rtl-officeWFM2 jqx-item jqx-item-officeWFM2 jqx-menu-item jqx-menu-item-officeWFM2 jqx-rc-all jqx-rc-all-officeWFM2" role="menuitem">
<span style="position: relative; left: 3px; top: -2px;">Datos entidades</span>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

I need the code in Selenium Webdriver to select, for example, "Usuarios" option

MAIN WINDOW AND CLICK BUTTON "Configuración"

Comment: Do you need to click on the Settings button to see the drop-down menu or do you need to just hover it with your mouse? Perhaps there's your problem.

Comment: @Pablo Cabanillas, Is your menu opens while click on Setting icon or just hovering mouse over there ?

Comment: Hi @Cosmin I need whith selenium do click on the icon named "Configuración" to choose an option. Its the same to do it in background or not
Many thanks

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)).  By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Comment: @kayess Rolled back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are seeing the submenu by hovering the configuration image then use `Actions` class to perform the action hover and click on a menu in below way :

```
WebElement configMenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul/li[@role='menuitem']/img[contains(@title,'Config')]"));
WebElement  UsuariosSubmenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul/li/span[normalize-space()='Usuarios']"));

Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(configMenu).clickAndHold(UsuariosSubmenu).click().build().perform();
```

Comment: Hi @Tuks If I use your code the right side is a WebElement and the left is a String. I have a error. Do you have any solution for this?
thanks

Comment: Sorry @Pablo Cabanillas, Its my mistake its a webElement leftside. I have updated the code

Comment: Hi again @Tucks. I've changed the strings for WebElement but doesn't work
The problem is in the last line action.moveToElement...
The error in console is
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: (119.9749984741211, -73.64999389648438) is out of bounds of viewport width (1366) and height (659)
So Sorry for all the questions but is my firs time with Selenium and Programing Languaje

Comment: I thing this is an issue which is already reported here https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/6468 . update your browser and selenium jars . Same thing is working here . m using Selenium 3.0.4 and FF 52